# Is there any difference between run maven as sudo and without sudo?

Tags: maven

I am using maven and JavaFX Maven Plugin. Maven will download jar from repository and save it to ~/.m2 directory. But if I use maven as sudo. For example, if I type `sudo mvn com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:fix-classpath`, is there any difference with the command without sudo? Does maven download the plugin and save it to ~/.m2 as well?

I ask this question because I run this command both under sudo and no-sudo. It seems maven will re-download the plugin each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is related to this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/422352/what-is-sudo-hiu-for).
So the answer to your question, would be if you are not changing the home directory while executing sudo, maven will download plugins to your user .m2 directory.